# Searching for HDMI searches for [hdmi]

Tags: support, search

I'm 100% sure I saw [a question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/54290/can-the-official-7-touch-display-be-used-at-the-same-time-as-an-hdmi-monitor) about HDMI which may not have been asked more than 4 hours ago, but it was not in the result list when I entered `HDMI` in the search field.

Then I noticed: when I enter "HDMI" as search term, it searches for the tag [hdmi](/questions/tagged/hdmi) instead. Is this the expected behavior? And is it really my task to find out that I have to enter `"HDMI"` to get other results?

Can we at least have an indicator that some magic happened, e.g.

> You entered *HDMI*. We're looking for questions tagged [hdmi](/questions/tagged/hdmi) instead. Search for `"HDMI"` instead.

Comment: I've added the tag to that question in case this is the cause of any confusion.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is expected behavior.

See what happens when you search for *status-completed* here. If you don't want to search for the tag, use quotes. `"status-completed"` or `"hdmi"` should do the trick.

[image]

Comment: Well, that's what I found out as well. It may also be the expected behavior. But doing magic without informing the user is not nice. I'm human. I can't recognize magic

Comment: I bet you 14 million dollars that's not the only magic you can't recognize. ;)

Comment: @ThomasWeller I think the interface has evolved over time to reflect something about a median in the user base -- sort of like an IDE, some of it may be perplexing, counter-intuitive, un- or obscurely documented, etc., but that's a difficult set of engineering questions to chew on: Can you cater to all skill levels without stepping on the toes of others?  If so, are the resources available?  If not, what are the priorities? And so on...

Comment: By analogy, the trend in e.g., mobile apps seems to be *no documentation* -- hopefully the user is just familiar with whatever convention might imply in context (as I think is the case here) or else it is "gramma still can't use a VCR", and hopefully either gramma can afford a consultant or there is some family or community group around to provide her with assistance.

Comment: @goldilocks, *no documentation* fits the Pi quite well.